# Increasing efficiency and time of my loops

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I was hoping somebody could help me with increasing the efficiency of my for loops.
I read that numpy vectorisation increases speed by "up to 74,000 faster", but didn't find much documentation on it.

I was wondering how others would increase the speed of this code.

```
from mplsoccer import Sbapi,Sbopen
import pandas as pd 
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np 
import io

parser = Sbopen(dataframe=True)
matches = parser.match(43,3)
matchids = list(matches.match_id.unique())

data = []
#The following for-loop concates approx 429 Dataframes of up to 30,000 rows each
for i in tqdm(matchids):
    event = parser.event(i)[0]
    data.append(event)
data = pd.concat(data)

data = data.merge(matches[['match_id','home_team_name','away_team_name']], on='match_id')
data = data[(data['type_name']=='Pass') & (data['outcome_name'].isna()) | (data['type_name']=='Carry') & (data['outcome_name'].isna())]
data = data[['match_id','type_name','possession_team_name','home_team_name','away_team_name','x','y','end_x','end_y']]


xT = """
0.00638303  0.00779616  0.00844854  0.00977659  0.01126267  0.01248344  0.01473596  0.0174506   0.02122129  0.02756312  0.03485072  0.0379259
0.00750072  0.00878589  0.00942382  0.0105949   0.01214719  0.0138454   0.01611813  0.01870347  0.02401521  0.02953272  0.04066992  0.04647721
0.0088799   0.00977745  0.01001304  0.01110462  0.01269174  0.01429128  0.01685596  0.01935132  0.0241224   0.02855202  0.05491138  0.06442595
0.00941056  0.01082722  0.01016549  0.01132376  0.01262646  0.01484598  0.01689528  0.0199707   0.02385149  0.03511326  0.10805102  0.25745362
0.00941056  0.01082722  0.01016549  0.01132376  0.01262646  0.01484598  0.01689528  0.0199707   0.02385149  0.03511326  0.10805102  0.25745362
0.0088799   0.00977745  0.01001304  0.01110462  0.01269174  0.01429128  0.01685596  0.01935132  0.0241224   0.02855202  0.05491138  0.06442595
0.00750072  0.00878589  0.00942382  0.0105949   0.01214719  0.0138454   0.01611813  0.01870347  0.02401521  0.02953272  0.04066992  0.04647721
0.00638303  0.00779616  0.00844854  0.00977659  0.01126267  0.01248344  0.01473596  0.0174506   0.02122129  0.02756312  0.03485072  0.0379259
"""
xT = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(xT), sep="\t",header=None)
xT = np.array(xT)
xT_rows, xT_cols = xT.shape
data['x1_bin'] = pd.cut(data['x'], bins=xT_cols, labels=False)
data['y1_bin'] = pd.cut(data['y'], bins=xT_rows, labels=False)
data['x2_bin'] = pd.cut(data['end_x'], bins=xT_cols, labels=False)
data['y2_bin'] = pd.cut(data['end_y'], bins=xT_rows, labels=False)
data['start_zone_value'] = data[['x1_bin', 'y1_bin']].apply(lambda x: xT[x[1]][x[0]], axis=1)
data['end_zone_value'] = data[['x2_bin', 'y2_bin']].apply(lambda x: xT[x[1]][x[0]], axis=1)
data['xT'] = data['end_zone_value'] - data['start_zone_value']
hometeamxt = []
awayteamxt = []
for match_id in tqdm(data['match_id']):
    match = data[data['match_id'] == match_id]
    home_xt = match[match['possession_team_name'] == match['home_team_name']]['xT'].sum()
    away_xt = match[match['possession_team_name'] == match['away_team_name']]['xT'].sum()
    hometeamxt.append(home_xt)
    awayteamxt.append(away_xt)
data['homext']=hometeamxt
data['awayxt']=awayteamxt
xtData = data.drop_duplicates(subset = 'match_id', keep = 'first').drop(['xT', 'possession_team_name'], axis = 1)
```

the slowest for loop tends to be the first one

```
for i in tqdm(matchids):
    event = parser.event(i)[0]
    data.append(event)
data = pd.concat(data)
```

Comment: Sorry to anyone who has looked at this code - there was an error which I've fixed.

Comment: It seems to me this question is more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Comment: @itprorh66, we have answered a lot of numpy/pandas 'remove loops' questions on SO.

Comment: Looks like your loop loads a large number of files and collects the dataframes in a list.  No room for 'vectorization' there.  Then you do one pandas `concat`.  That's as direct and fast as you can do.

Comment: Specifically, you should read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Comment: You use a couple of specialized packages, so it will be hard to `numpy/pandas` users to help you.  And there's no real data to test changes on.  Where is did you see this "74000" times claim? Without its explanation about how "vectorization" works, it's a worthless claim.  At its core, "numpy vectorization" means replacing python level operations (especially loops) with compiled numpy methods - operating on numpy arrays.  Same applies to `pandas`.  "vectorization" isn't a magic wand you can wave your code.  It is just using the packages correctly,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The block you cite isn't the slower part of your code. All the time of consumed by that block is spent inside the `parser.event` function. This function has 2 operations:

- Get data from Github
- Process that data into a DataFrame

The first operation can be made faster by using some asynchronous IO, but the second operation is CPU bound and thus harder to parallelize. So unless you want to update the Statsbomb library, there is little you can do here.

---

The slowest is the second `tqdm` loop:

```py
for match_id in tqdm(data['match_id']):
    match = data[data['match_id'] == match_id]
    home_xt = match[match['possession_team_name'] == match['home_team_name']]['xT'].sum()
    away_xt = match[match['possession_team_name'] == match['away_team_name']]['xT'].sum()
    hometeamxt.append(home_xt)
    awayteamxt.append(away_xt)
```

Here, a bad algorithm makes the `for` loop even worse. You want to find the summary for 64 matches, split into home and away sides. However, you iter through 100k data points for those matches, calculate the summary again and again, only to drop the duplicates at the end.

It's obviously a lot better to calculate the summary only once:

```py
# Indicate if the stats on the row are for Home or Away team
is_home = data["possession_team_name"] == data["home_team_name"]

# The total xT for each match, split by Home (True) and Away (False)
xT = data.groupby([is_home, "match_id"])["xT"].sum()

# Combine the pieces together
xtData = pd.concat([
    # Here's the big stat dataframe. We no longer need all the detailed stats,
    # just some basic info about each match. In fact, I think you only need the
    # match_id, home_team_name and away_team_name from this frame.
    data.drop(columns=["possession_team_name", "xT"]).drop_duplicates(subset="match_id").set_index("match_id"),
    # Extract the xT for the Home team
    xT.xs(True).rename("homext"),
    # Extract the xT for the Away team
    xT.xs(False).rename("awayxt"),
], axis=1)
```

The above code took 52ms vs. 8m of the original on my computer.